# Re-Route Mail to a port other than 25

Tags: redirect, email

Is there a way to route mail to another port? I have an email account attached to my laptop that I'd like to be able to send and receive mail from. Due to mobility, I'll be passing through various networks that will probably block this port.

My dynamic DNS provider allows me to utilize web-forwards for MX domains; is this possible? where I can web forward to a domain:port which is managed by my DNS provider when I traverse between networks. If not, is there a way?

Of course i could use web-mail or relay-forwarding from my home server, but that's not geeky enough.

Comment: Why do you need MX record for your laptop? Usually you have a server that receives the mail via SMTP that you then fetch via what ever method suits you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. You can't ask other mail servers to contact you on a different port.

Generally, it is a bad idea to run a mail server on random networks. It's inherently unreliable, and likely to land your domain on a bad reputation list. If you want to run a mail server, get a server at a reliable provider and set up your MX there. You can configure your laptop to forward its mail through that server.

Comment: I can forward through my home server, and I somewhat expected this answer. I'm quite naive when it comes to networking, so why would manipulating of my MX domain not work? I'm willing to experiment, but not at the whims of angering my DNS service provider (despite that I pay them).

Comment: MX records only dictate what host to connect to, not what port to connect on.

Comment: Possibly some time in the future MX records will be deprecated and replaced with SRV records which would be able to point to arbitrary ports. However, right now, port 25 is the only option if you want to run a server capable of receiving inbound mails.